# JScrollPanel and Text Wrap Not Yet Functioning

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jscrollbar

I'm expecting a box with text that wraps and a scrollbar that appears when the window becomes too small to display all text.  Neither of these elements of functionality are present, however.

```
  JFrame f = new JFrame();
  JRootPane root = f.getRootPane();
  Container content = root.getContentPane();
  JButton button = new JButton("Generate New Phrase");
  JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
  JTextArea info = new JTextArea();
  JScrollPane scrilla = new JScrollPane(info);

  public CorporateSloganGenerator() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      phraseGenerator = new PhraseGeneratorFromFile();

      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      infoPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      info.setColumns(40);
      info.setRows(20);
      infoPanel.add(info);
      ControlListener listensUp = new ControlListener();
      button.addActionListener(listensUp);
      content.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      content.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      root.setDefaultButton(button);    

      info.add(scrilla);
      info.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.ITALIC, 28));
      button.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
      info.setLineWrap(true);
      info.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      info.setEditable(false);
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.pack();
```

Comment: Why are you adding the scroll pane to the text area?

Comment: Hm I've tried changing that to infoPanel.add(scrilla); but no difference was made.  I've been changing around a lot of things in hope of something clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, a component is set as a scroll panes view when you want to provide scrollable support, for example, instead of...

```
info.add(scrilla);
```

You should using something like...

```
scrilla.setViewportView(info);
```

You should then add this to the frame...

```
f.add(scrilla);
```

Before making it visible...

Also, while not entirely required, it would make sense to `pack` the frame before you show it, for example...

```
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

You may also like to take a look at [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks, I have a little trouble remaining after using the code you provided.  There's a big gray box over some, if not most of the text, and this goes away as I scroll around.  What's making this appear?

Comment: This gray box, by the way, goes away when f.pack is removed.

Comment: Do you have a runnable example I can look at?

Comment: I could send it to you; it's a lot of code, though.

Comment: Zip, post it to a free file share and send me the link ;)

Comment: Hm, I have it zipped up but I don't have any fileshare accounts.  Could I e-mail it to you instead?

Comment: For the moment, just post the link so I can have a look at it ;P

Comment: gotchu  I took out the f.pack() that was right above f.setVisible(true); http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/474571/vdr3Project3-zip.html

Comment: This could be a result of creating the UI within the main thread and not the EDT, take a look at [initial threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)